# Changing visibility of a view from GONE to VISIBLE causes lag and slow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout, visibility

I'm getting stuck at this problem.

I have an activity like attached image.
by default, in the toolbar, display only layout1, then when user click on layout1, layout2 appear/gone. I'm using layout1.setOnClickListener, and set visibility for layout2 ( layout2.visibility = View.Visible). It works, but it's very lag and slow. And in my case, I dont want to use invisible property because of UI looking.

I'm searching solution on the internet and I think when I change layout of a view, it will redraw other view. In this case, redrawing my listView may take a lot of time.
Can you give me some solutions? Thankyou very much.

[Update]
Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="@dimen/notice_list_toolbar_elevation"
        android:layout_alignParentStart = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--layout 1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/keyword_txt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_textbox"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:hint="検索"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--layout 2-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/date_search_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/date_search_display"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:text="売日"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/auction_date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:text="@string/not_setting_date"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                    android:text="検索"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tab_strip"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/notice_list_tab_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/notice_list_tab_text_size"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="@dimen/notice_list_tab_indicator_height"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/tab_strip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my kotlin code(same as Java)

```
layout1.setOnClickListener{
        if(layout2.visibility == View.GONE){
            layout2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            layout2.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does your Android monitor show something??

Comment: what do you have in the layout 2 please show.. (xml)

Comment: provide your javacode

Comment: I've updated my code. Please see it again. Tks..

Comment: Remove the android:animateLayoutChanges="true" in your xml. It animates visibility changes and not always fits your expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`,

when you use `GONE` , your ui elements has no dimension and viewgroup doesn't calculate  it's size .but if you use invisible your view has dimension but it is hidden.

changing `GONE` to `VISIBLE`  makes view to re-render and makes your viewgroup again and it cause lag and problem on re-rendering.

Comment: Is there another way? Because in my case, if I use INVISIBLE instead of GONE, it'll make the toolbar has a space for invisible layout.

Comment: you can set height zero from start and after sometime that you need increase your height

Comment: you can use setLayoutParam everytime that you need to chang height and width